# Is it possible somehow to charge when users upload a certain number of images of their creative products without using In-app-purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase

We are in the process of producing an app where users can exhibit their own creative crafts and shop with each other for free and have full access to the app. We know from the rules that google and apple only allow digital goods using there in-app-purchases; If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.
Our question: Is it possible somehow to charge when users upload a certain number of images of their creative products without using in-app purchases?

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a list of apps that may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase, see paragraph [3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#other-purchase-methods) in the App Store Review Guidelines.

For example: If those creative crafts are physical, your app falls under `3.1.3(e) Goods and Services Outside of the App`, and you're allowed to use other payment methods.

Comment: Thanks . The creative crafts are phsysical products which are sold outside the app but the vendor and the buyer takes care of the buying and selling and payments them selfes so we need no payment methods  there to collect money. But what we want is to give the vendor some benefits  like a headline on the product, text in bold, and so on, so that he can sell his individual craft faster. The vendor Should be able to buy Some  benefits for an individual/single product? Our question: Is it possible to use other  ways to unlock feateres and so on without using in-app-purchase? Maybe rule 3.1.4?

Comment: Ah, so you want the users to pay to be more prominent in your app? I think, since they pay for more/better features solely within your app, you won't get around in-app purchases. Rule 3.1.4 does not apply to your app.

Comment: If you also offer the service on other platforms or your web site, you could maybe apply for rule `3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services`. Why don't you want to use in-app purchases?

Comment: Thanks.  I dont want to use in-app-purchases cause the payments options are limited for Danish users. Only 7-8% of the Danish people uses apple pay and google pay. Thats why.  So I am looking for another solution which in the end Will be accepted by google and apple? And Maybe rule 3.1.3(b) is possible but I need to be sure? We are looking for Some kind of opoortunity for the vendor to boost his product? And the vendor Should of cause pay for those benefits?

Comment: And regarding rule 3.1.3(b) So If We provide both a website and an app offering these feateres/benefits inside The app and on the website for the vendor, then its possible to use other payments methods Than in app-purchase?   And Another question? our app is being programmed in flutter. Does it present any challenges?

Comment: In-app purchases have nothing to do with Apple Pay. You pay for in-app purchases with the payment option you added to your Apple account (e.g. credit card). Unfortunately, I have no experiences with flutter.

Comment: Ok. So if you choose in-app-purchases you have to have an Apple and a google account and add a e.g Credits card  to pay for Those feateres, subscription and so on?  I am not sure the danish users are used to paying through there Google and apple account? I dont Think they are.  If the users Were used to doing that it would be fine with in-app-purchases but if not then I Think I Will apply for rule 3.1.3(b)?

Comment: Question: Do you Know any app where there is a in-app-purchases? Then I could test that point of view

Comment: For each platform (Android and iOS), it is more or less mandatory to have an account with a valid payment method stated. Therefore I am sure most users are used to pay this way. At least on the App Store, you can download any app (maybe not from the free section), and there will be in-app purchases.

Comment: So we have two options as I See it:    1. rule 3.1.3(b) So If We provide both a website and an app offering these feateres/benefits inside The app and on the website for the vendor, and the vendor get access both platforms  then its possible to use other payments methods Than in app-purchase  just like rule 3.1.3(b)          2.  If we use in-app-purchase provided by google and apple and pay 30% in fee.    Question: What would you recommend and why?  And regarding In-app-purchase: How does it work? can you add buttons To unlock feateres, subscriptions and so on inside The app?

Comment: In-app purchase is not a payment method. It means that your customers can buy extra content or features in your app, and they pay for those things with the payment method they have associated with their account. If you solely build an app, I recommend using in-app purchases because Apple handles everything around payment (provide different payment methods, retries when payment failed, etc.) for you. See here for more information about in-app purchases: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: If you provide your service cross-platform (iOS, Android, and website), Apple allows you, based on the linked rules, to implement the payment yourself. This can be a lot of work or you use a third-party solution which in turn will also take its share. So, I wouldn't create a website solely for the purpose to circumvent in-app purchases and Apple's share (it is only 15% if you are under one million revenue per year.

Comment: Thanks. Are the in-app-purchase only automatic renewel or are you able to renew it  your self?

Comment: The link I posted earlier shows a list of all possible in-app purchases and there is also a subscription the user needs to re-new himself